# GUID Information

Tags: generator, guid, uuid

No idea why but I have been interested in GUIDs recently. After looking at a few of them I wrote a function to generate them but verifying them with http://guid.us/Test/GUID they don't pass it. A few GUIDs from my generator:

```
914HK4XO-GF46-EDNY-07AW-FDB0ZHI8ZLP8
OHF7XXMG-E1YK-9EOL-G94E-WC9MCSFI0CXE
0X1X295G-Q394-DX8N-5C39-5I858I7WFRHH
```

What makes these any different to the valid GUIDs below?

```
C5D850D4-4273-4170-A3C5-61B84F88105E
AAF77D1B-D1CF-4562-B624-204DC876CA17
18C50D98-D3F7-4C3A-9E67-CFAFB3D53F38
```

Call me blind but I don't see a difference between the two.

Comment: Did you just slap together a bunch of random digits?  GUIDs are not totally random (just mostly.)   You should read the spec.  http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt

Comment: @RyanV.Bissell That's what I was looking for. I couldn't find anything like that but I learnt they have to pass this regex `/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i`

Comment: Why is there no mention of the fact that the generated GUID values are not hex?

Answer (score 1):

The thirteenth element in the GUID is the GUID version.  In the valid GUIDs, they are all "4" (i.e. Version 4).  There is more than likely a conforming GUID library in whatever language you are using. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier for a detailed explanation of the various formats.

Comment: I'm using Javascript and I like trying to write my own stuff before using a library.

Comment: Understood.  The site I just referenced in my edit might give you a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the possible cause could be that a GUID is not just 32 bytes of random and unique data. It has to also conform to some guidelines. The closest thing is I guess a credit card number. They are all unique, but at the same time not every unique number can be a valid credit card number. There is an algorithm that checks for its validity as well. By the way, I have only "heard" about this thing about credit card numbers, so I am not 100% sure that that's how they work.

Answer (score 0):

UUIDs (aka GUIDs) are structurally defined by a "varient".  For example, RFC 4122 outlines a specific UUID varient  with five versions.

It might be helpful to study RFC 4122 to better understand the significant bits that define this varient and versions. It is possible to observe these bits and "reverse engineer" a UUID, revealing the UID varient, version, etc.

You can research UUIDs using ["Mahonri Moriancumer's
UUID and GUID Generator and Forensics"](http://www.mahonri.info/cgi/uuid.cgi)  This site may help you better understand UUID formats, varients, versions, etc.